# Abstract homotopy invariance of homology

Tags: category-theory, homological-algebra, homotopy-theory

When topology is involved, we know (singular) homology is homotopy invariant. However, homology and homotopy can be discussed in much more general contexts.

Living in $\mathsf{Ch}_\bullet(R\mathsf{Mod})$ for instance, it seems reasonable to ask whether the formalism continues to behave as it did when we had topology, i.e that homology would remain homotopy invariant. Here I mean homotopy in the sense of cylinder objects, which are, in our context, given by tensor products with the interval-complex.

Suppose there's a homotopy equivalence between two chain complexes. Do they have the same homology objects?

If it is true, what is the essence of the proof? I assume it does not involve games with simplices as does the proof for singular homology in Hatcher, so what does "make it true"?

If it were true, we'd be able to get the homotopy invariance of singular homology for free without playing with simplices, no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Homology is a representable functor on the homotopy category of chain complexes. Namely, in the homotopy category of chain complexes of $R$-modules $H_n$ is represented by $R[n]$, which you should think of as a chain complex incarnation of the $n$-sphere.

You don't get the homotopy invariance of singular homology for free this way since you still need to know that a homotopy equivalence of spaces induces a chain homotopy equivalence.

Comment: For homotopy invariance, is it already enough that the homology functor is defined on the homotopy category? How should I think of its representability?
Lastly, where can I find this result?

Comment: @Exterior: yes. The values of any representable functor on a category are automatically invariant under isomorphisms in that category (which in this case is chain homotopy equivalences). This is probably an exercise in various homological algebra textbooks.

Comment: When you say homotopy category of chain complexes, do you formally mean quotienting Hom-sets by chain-homotopic arrows or "abstract-homotopic" arrows? These *are* the same whatever the case though, right?

Comment: @Exterior: if they're not the same, then "abstract-homotopic" is the wrong notion.

Comment: By "abstract-homotopic" here, I mean there exists an arrow $X\times I\rightarrow Y$ where $X,Y,I$ are chain complexes, $I$ being the inverval complex as [here](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/interval+object+in+chain+complexes), such that its compositions on the inclusions $e_0,e_1$ are respectively $f,g$. The cylinder $X\times I$ can be taken either grading-wise as $X_n\oplus X_n \oplus X_{n-1}$ or as the tensor product $X\otimes I$. This seems like the right notion, I just want to make sure the homotopy categories are the same.

Comment: @Exterior: yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: Where can I find a reference for the representability of homology? I looked around online and only found much more complicated things.

Comment: @Exterior: I don't know. This is why I don't pay a lot of attention to textbooks. It's not a hard exercise to just do.

Comment: I just don't understand the intuition, for instance behind thinking of $R[n]$ as a chain complex reincarnation of a sphere, or behind the fact homology is represented by such "sphere".

Comment: @Exterior: the intuition comes from the Dold-Kan theorem, which can be interpreted as telling you that you should think of chain complexes as roughly being topological abelian groups, and of the homology groups of chain complexes as roughly being the *homotopy* groups of topological abelian groups. It's also worth looking up the Dold-Thom theorem, which is one way to justify this interpretation of homology in terms of homotopy.

Comment: @Exterior: there are a lot of other things to say here. I think your focus on "abstract homotopy" is a distraction; if you want to learn some abstractions that will help you understand the way in which chain complexes are like spaces, the basic such abstraction is the theory of model categories and the more modern such abstraction is the theory of $\infty$-categories. In particular, you should learn something about the general notion of homotopy limits and colimits. In any setting where you have a reasonable such notion there is an abstract operation called suspension you can perform...

Comment: ...which satisfies a certain higher universal property, and in particular which is left adjoint to an abstract operation called taking loop spaces, and something like the $n$-sphere appears when you suspend something like the "point" $n$ times. In chain complexes suspension turns out to just be shifting up by $1$ and taking loops turns out to just be shifting down by $1$ so the adjunction is easy to see and in fact the two operations are inverse.

Comment: Thank you very (very) much for the detailed reply! I will try to learn about $\infty$-categories.

Answer (score 3):

If you have a chain homotopy equivalence, then it induces isomorphisms in homology. There are various ways to see this – but here is the outline of a hands-on proof:

1. Show that nullhomotopic chain maps induce zero maps in homology.
2. Deduce that homotopic chain maps induce the same map in homology.
3. Deduce that chain homotopy equivalences induce isomorphisms in homology.

However, to go from homotopy of continuous maps to chain homotopy requires *some* geometric input – after all, $C_{\bullet} (X \times Y)$ is not literally the same as $C_{\bullet} (X) \otimes C_{\bullet} (Y)$. (That said, they are chain homotopy equivalent: this is the Eilenberg–Zilber theorem.)

Comment: I think perhaps my question wasn't clear enough (or I'm missing something, which is also likely). I'm asking about the abstract machines without any geometry. Just a homotopy equivalence in the abstract cylinder-object sense, and whether chain complexes homotopy-equivalent in this sense have the same homology objects. So no topological spaces :)

Comment: A homotopy equivalence in the cylinder sense is exactly a chain homotopy equivalence.